How to make ePaper work in landscape mode with RPi Pico?
I bought a 2.9inch ePaper display for RPi Pico (296 × 128 Pixels, Black / White / Red, SPI Interface) from WaveShare.
I found several MicroPython drivers for 2.9" ePaper on Waveshare's GitHub:
https://github.com/waveshareteam/Pico_ePaper_Code
Unfortunately, there are no explanations / comments / doc.strings in the source code whatsoever! I tested all drivers for 2.9" displays, some of them did not work. I have no experience with C, only with Python.
What I did:
I took one of scripts that worked and cleaned it and annotated it to the best of my ability, trying to understand the logic behind it to the best of my ability. Please, see the script below (it works in Portrait mode).
What I need:

I want to make this display to work in Landscape mode. I tried swapping width and height. I also tried changing buffer mode from framebuf.MONO_HLSB  to framebuf.MONO_VLSB Nothing worked. Could you suggest what else can I do?
When I run this script, the ePaper display flickers. I do not understand why! How can I reduce flickering / flashing?


import gc
import time
import framebuf
from machine import Pin, SPI
from micropython import const


def profile(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        gc.collect()
        start_mem = gc.mem_free()
        start_t = time.ticks_ms()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        fin_t = time.ticks_ms()
        fin_mem = gc.mem_free()
        print(f'{func.__name__} took: {time.ticks_diff(fin_t, start_t)} ms to finish')
        print(f'{func.__name__} used around {start_mem - fin_mem} B of memory')

    return wrapper

# ! Display Dimentions:
EPD_HEIGHT = const(296)  # * screen height 296 pixels; type integer.
EPD_WIDTH = const(128)  # * screen width 128 pixels; type integer.
BUF_FORMAT = framebuf.MONO_HLSB
# ! COLORS:
BLACK = 0x00
WHITE = 0xff
# ! Pins:
CS_PIN = 9  # * chip select (CS) pin (and start it high)
RST_PIN = 12  # * Reset
DC_PIN = 8  # * data/command control pin, write command when DC=0; write data when DC=1.
BUSY_PIN = 13
FULL_UPDATE = 0
PART_UPDATE = 1
# ! Display Commands:
PANEL_SETTING = const(0x00)
POWER_SETTING = const(0x01)
POWER_OFF = const(0x02)
POWER_OFF_SEQUENCE_SETTING = const(0x03)
POWER_ON = const(0x04)
POWER_ON_MEASURE = const(0x05)
BOOSTER_SOFT_START = const(0x06)
DEEP_SLEEP = const(0x07)
DATA_START_TRANSMISSION_1 = const(0x10)
DATA_STOP = const(0x11)
DISPLAY_REFRESH = const(0x12)
DATA_START_TRANSMISSION_2 = const(0x13)
SET_MEM_ADDR = const(0x20)
SET_COL_ADDR = const(0x21)
SET_PAGE_ADDR = const(0x22)
SET_DISP_START_LINE = const(0x40)
VCOM_AND_DATA_INTERVAL_SETTING = const(0x50)
TCON_RESOLUTION = const(0x61)
GET_STATUS = const(0x71)
AUTO_MEASURE_VCOM = const(0x80)

class EPD_2in9_B:
    # ? This Class inherits from MicroPython class FrameBuffer.
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = EPD_WIDTH
        self.height = EPD_HEIGHT
        self.dc_pin = Pin(DC_PIN, Pin.OUT, value=0)
        self.cs_pin = Pin(CS_PIN, Pin.OUT)
        self.busy_pin = Pin(BUSY_PIN, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
        self.reset_pin = Pin(RST_PIN, Pin.OUT, value=0)
        # ? The default pins for SPI(1) are: sck=Pin(6), mosi=Pin(8), miso=Pin(7)
        # ? when increased the baudrate=20_000_000, no text appered on the screen.
        self.spi = SPI(1)
        self.spi.init(baudrate = 100_000)
        # * The display is stored as a list of bytes where each byte is eight consecutive pixels, either set to 1 to display a dark pixel or 0 for white (or clear).
        # * heiht*width // 8 = (296*128) / 8 = 4736
        self.buffer_black = bytearray(self.height * self.width // 8)
        self.buffer_red = bytearray(self.height * self.width // 8)
        # * The first argument is the byte array, with and height are self explanatory, and framebuf.MONO_HLSB means that this framebuffer is a mono (1-bit) image, with horizontal bits stored as a byte.
        self.imageblack = framebuf.FrameBuffer(self.buffer_black, self.width, self.height, BUF_FORMAT)
        self.imagered = framebuf.FrameBuffer(self.buffer_red, self.width, self.height, BUF_FORMAT)
        self.init()

    def digital_write(self, pin, value):
        '''
        Pin.value([x])
        If the argument is supplied then this method sets the digital logic level of the pin. 
        The argument x can be anything that converts to a boolean. 
        If it converts to True, the pin is set to state 1, otherwise it is set to state 0.
        '''
        pin.value(value)

    def digital_read(self, pin):
        '''
        Use the value() method to check the present value on a pin set up to be in input mode. 
        With polling, you can use MicroPython code to monitor the value of a pin. 
        During polling, the system constantly checks the value of the pin.
        '''
        return pin.value()

    def spi_writebyte(self, data):
        '''
        SPI.write(buf): write the bytes contained in buffer.
        '''
        self.spi.write(bytearray(data))

    # * Hardware reset
    def reset(self):
    # * If we have a reset pin, do a hardware reset by toggling it.
        if self.reset_pin:
            self.digital_write(self.reset_pin, False)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.digital_write(self.reset_pin, True)
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def send_command(self, command):
        self.digital_write(self.dc_pin, 0)
        self.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 0)
        self.spi_writebyte([command])
        self.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 1)

    def send_data(self, data):
        self.digital_write(self.dc_pin, 1)
        self.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 0)
        self.spi_writebyte([data])
        self.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 1)

    @profile
    def ReadBusy(self):
        print('ePaper is busy!')
        self.send_command(GET_STATUS)
        while (self.digital_read(self.busy_pin) == 0): 
            self.send_command(GET_STATUS)
            time.sleep_ms(10) 
        print('Busy release')

    @profile
    def init(self):
        print('Initializind the display!')
        self.reset()
        self.send_command(POWER_ON)
        self.ReadBusy()  # ? waiting for the electronic paper IC to release the idle signal
        self.send_command(PANEL_SETTING )  # panel setting
        self.send_data(0x0f)  # LUT from OTP,128x296
        self.send_data(0x89)  # Temperature sensor, boost and other related timing settings
        self.send_command(TCON_RESOLUTION)  #resolution setting
        self.send_data (AUTO_MEASURE_VCOM)
        self.send_data (POWER_SETTING)
        self.send_data (0x28)
        self.send_command(VCOM_AND_DATA_INTERVAL_SETTING)
        self.send_data(0x77)  # WBmode:VBDF 17|D7 VBDW 97 VBDB 57
        return 0

    def TurnOnDisplay(self):
        self.send_command(DISPLAY_REFRESH)
        self.ReadBusy()

    def display(self):
        self.send_command(0x10)
        self.send_data1(self.buffer_black)
        self.send_command(0x13)
        self.send_data1(self.buffer_red)   
        self.TurnOnDisplay()
        
    def send_data1(self, buf):
        '''
        send_data1() is used only in Clear()
        '''
        self.digital_write(self.dc_pin, 1)
        self.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray(buf))
        self.digital_write(self.cs_pin, 1)

    @profile
    def Clear(self, color_black, color_red):
        self.send_command(DATA_START_TRANSMISSION_1)
        self.send_data1([color_black] * self.height * int(self.width / 8))
        print([color_black] * self.height * int(self.width / 8))
        print(f"bytearray length: {self.height * int(self.width / 8)}")
        self.send_command(DATA_START_TRANSMISSION_2)
        self.send_data1([color_red] * self.height * int(self.width / 8))
        self.TurnOnDisplay()

        '''
        high = self.height
        if( self.width % 8 == 0) :
            wide =  self.width // 8
        else :
            wide =  self.width // 8 + 1
        self.send_command(0x10)
        self.send_data1([color] * high * wide)
        self.send_command(0x13)
        self.send_data1([~color] * high * wide)
        self.SetFullReg()
        self.TurnOnDisplay()'''

    def sleep(self):
        self.send_command(POWER_OFF) # power off
        self.ReadBusy()
        self.send_command(DEEP_SLEEP) # deep sleep
        self.send_data(0xA5)
        time.sleep_ms(2000)
        self.digital_write(self.reset_pin, 0)

if __name__=='__main__':
    START_TIME = time.time()
    epd = EPD_2in9_B()
    # ! Clear the Screen (only white color):
    print("Clearing screen!")
    epd.Clear(WHITE, WHITE)
    epd.imageblack.fill(WHITE)
    epd.imagered.fill(WHITE)
    # ! Display text:
    print("Displaying text!")
    epd.imageblack.text("Waveshare", 0, 10, BLACK)
    epd.imagered.text("ePaper-2.9-B", 0, 25, BLACK)
    epd.imageblack.text("Raspberry_Pi_Pico W", 0, 40, BLACK)
    epd.imagered.text("Hello World", 0, 55, BLACK)
    epd.display()
    time.sleep_ms(2000)
    print("Drawing rectangles!")
    epd.imageblack.rect(10, 150, 40, 40, 0x00)
    epd.imagered.fill_rect(60, 150, 40, 40, 0x00)
    epd.display()
    time.sleep_ms(2000)
    print("Clearing screen!")
    epd.Clear(WHITE, WHITE)
    time.sleep_ms(2000)
    print("Sleeping!")
    epd.sleep()
    # ! Measure time:
    FINISH_TIME = time.time()
    duration = FINISH_TIME - START_TIME
    print(f"\nProcess duration is {duration:.3f} seconds.")



when does the display flicker?

@jsotola During my trials, flickering appears when Clear() method is called.

the clear function may be something that is implemented in the display hardware

@jsotola Is it safe to comment out epd.Clear(WHITE, WHITE) and try running the script?

why wouldn't it be safe?
